# How to combine information of two seasons in one boxplot using the same label?

Tags: r, boxplot

I'm searching for help, I want to put two boxplots in the same treatment. I have two season, 5 treatments for each one, the label is a, b, c, d, e, but I want that two individual boxplots (sason1 and season2) appear for each treatment. This is part of my script:

```
boxplot(t1$AL2,t1$BL2,t1$CL2,t1$DL2,t1$EL2, names=c("A1","B1","C1","D1","E1"), xlab="Treatment", ylab="Duration (Days)",main= "L2")

boxplot(t2$AL2,t2$BL2,t2$CL2,t2$DL2,t2$EL2, names=c("A2","B2","C2","D2","E2"), xlab="Treatment", ylab="Duration (Days)",main= "L2")
```

so, this is how they look individually, but I want to combine them to obtain just one chart and change the label A1...E1 and A2...E2 without the number indicating the season.

Thanks

Comment: You are looking for a way to combine plots? The Quick [R manual](https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html) shows you how.

Comment: Check this out [How to create a grouped boxplot in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479522/how-to-create-a-grouped-boxplot-in-r).