# How to group data by one variable while knowing (and plotting) the average and Q1,Q3 of other variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the top few rows of my data with it's `dput`:

```
head(Actigraph)
  Participant.code Condition Day.within.condition Standing Sitting Stepping Cycling
1           AE1_01       PRE                    1     2676   25521      117      67
2           AE1_01       PRE                    2    17594   14793        6       8
3           AE1_01       PRE                    3     2174   29371      799      57
4           AE1_01       PRE                    4      395   32001        4       1
5           AE1_01       PRE                    5       72   31979       24     326
6           AE1_01       DBN                    1    11993   11129      875      64
dput(head(Actigraph))
structure(list(Participant.code = c("AE1_01", "AE1_01", "AE1_01", 
"AE1_01", "AE1_01", "AE1_01"), Condition = c("PRE", "PRE", "PRE", 
"PRE", "PRE", "DBN"), Day.within.condition = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L), Standing = c(2676L, 17594L, 2174L, 395L, 72L, 11993L
), Sitting = c(25521L, 14793L, 29371L, 32001L, 31979L, 11129L
), Stepping = c(117L, 6L, 799L, 4L, 24L, 875L), Cycling = c(67L, 
8L, 57L, 1L, 326L, 64L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to `group_by(Condition)` and plot a box and whiskers for all 4 columns (Standing:Cylcing) PER condition.

So 4 plots (1 per condition), and within having 4 columns be displayed as box and whiskers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a grouped boxplot in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479522/how-to-create-a-grouped-boxplot-in-r), see answer by r2evans: reshaping to a longer format and then plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may reshape to 'long' format and then use `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
Actigraph %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = Standing:Cycling) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = Condition)) + 
     geom_boxplot()
```